# Is there a way to remove my email form git commits?

Tags: git, github, commit

I have been uploading my code to github for some time now. I've recently discovered that I have my personal email included with my commits and I want to remove it. How do I do that? Thank you in advance!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+change+email

Comment: You can use interactive rebase to re-edit commits and commit history. But be careful, since this will reconstruct git commit chain and can be tricky if you have merge commits or commits are spread over multiple branches.